# create_or_get with data from user input

Tags: python, flask, peewee, flask-peewee

Trying to implement a user registration form on a website I can't make user input to be added as a new user to the database. I'm using Flask with Peewee, and have:

```
nUser ={
        'email': request.form['e_mail'],
        'uname': request.form['username'],
        'pword': request.form['password'],                     
        'time': strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

}
nUser = User.create_or_get()
```

where nUser is temporary dict for new user. I should mention, that with [the official peewee docs](http://peewee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.create_or_get) I tried `nUser, created = User.create_or_get(nUser)` what returned an error of too many arguments.

A code about `User` class is below (stored in separate .py, but there is `from models import *` up there):

```
class User(Model):
    email=TextField()
    uname=TextField(unique=True)
    pword=TextField()
    time=TextField()

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

Although it looks like it "works" from a webuser side, no record is added to the database. Previously I did it with `User.select().where(User.uname......` and it worked, but now I would like to switch to `create_or_get()` method since it would shorten my code and looks more efficient. Logging in for old users works, so the connection and access to the DB is fine. I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: The documentation shows that the parameter is "**kwargs", so a single un-named dictionary will not work. Change it to `User.create_or_get(**nUser)`.

Comment: it was already answered below, but thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation that you link to show that `create_or_get` takes keyword arguments only. To pass a dict, you need to use the `**` syntax:

```
User.create_or_get(**nuser)
```